# Count length of a record stripping out html tags

Tags: mysql, regex, count

I am trying to get a grand total of review length, but people are allowed to add lists, tables, color, etc.  I would just like to get the count of the actual review characters.  Is there a way to use regex to strip out everything other than the real words to count the characters?  I am using mySQL 5.5 and here is the current query I have:

```
select sum(COALESCE(length(reviewTxt),0) + COALESCE(length(reviewTxt1),0) + COALESCE(length(reviewTxt2),0) + COALESCE(length(reviewTxt3),0) + COALESCE(length(reviewTxt4),0) + COALESCE(length(reviewTxt5),0) + COALESCE(length(reviewTxt6),0) + COALESCE(length(reviewTxt7),0) + COALESCE(length(reviewTxt8),0) + COALESCE(length(reviewTxt9),0) + COALESCE(length(reviewTxt10),0)) as totalLength
                    from set_reviews
```

Answer (score 0):

The following was taken from http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?656167-PHP-s-strip_tags%28%29-equivalent-MYSQL-function :

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

This is the php function strip_tags

```
delimiter ||

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS strip_tags||
CREATE FUNCTION strip_tags( x longtext) RETURNS longtext
LANGUAGE SQL NOT DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
DECLARE sstart INT UNSIGNED;
DECLARE ends INT UNSIGNED;
SET sstart = LOCATE('<', x, 1);
REPEAT
SET ends = LOCATE('>', x, sstart);
SET x = CONCAT(SUBSTRING( x, 1 ,sstart -1) ,SUBSTRING(x, ends +1 )) ;
SET sstart = LOCATE('<', x, 1);
UNTIL sstart < 1 END REPEAT;
return x;
END;
||
delimiter ;

mysql> SELECT strip_tags('<a href="HelloWorld.html"><B>Hi, mate!</B></a>') as strip_tags;

+------------+
| strip_tags |
+------------+
| Hi, mate!  |
+------------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: i am trying to add this function to my db and i keep getting the following error


 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter ||

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS strip_tags||
CREATE FUNCTION strip_tags( x' at line 1 

 Warnings: ---> 
   W (1): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter ||

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS strip_tags||
CREATE FUNCTION strip_tags( x' at line 1

Comment: Where are you executing this statement? DELIMITER isn't a MySQL statement - it is normally handled by the SQL client.

Comment: i tried adding it to the database itself to call like i have done in oracle.  I am programming in Coldfusion, not PHP, so I am not sure how this would be setup in there

Comment: I don't know what sql client you are using - look at the documentation. Essentially the delimeter statement is to allow you to separate the drop statement from the create statement. Execute them separately.

Comment: I use Navicat.  I will see what i can find out there